# cronjob every 4 weeks, not executing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, cron, shell

I am using cron on my Ubuntu headless server 18.04 and the following cron is not executing:

```
30 13 * * 6 test $((10#$(date +%W)%4)) -eq 1 && /bin/bash /backup/test.sh
```

I tested the command in shell:

```
test $((10#$(date +%W)%4)) -eq 1 && /bin/bash /backup/test.sh
```

and it works fine, but if it is in cron, it doesn't execute it.

Comment: Have you looked at the cron log? Is there a new line after the command in cron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## "Wrong" shell used in cron

Your test seems command to use syntax which may be "misinterpreted" by some shells other than `bash`.  Cron *by default* uses `/bin/sh` shell.

Possible fixes to choose from:

**a)** wrap `test` argument in single quotes and force "right" shell

```
0 13 * * 6 /bin/bash -c 'test $((10#$(date +%W)%4)) -eq 0' && …
```

**b)** move your test command to separate executable file with explicitly selected shell in shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec test "$((10#$(date +%W)%4))" -eq 1
```

**c)** change shell used by `cron`. In crontab add line

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

---

In your case specific case option "a" seems to be the best but similar problems may be best served by other options.

Comment: I don't think option **a** will work. In dash 0.5.10.2, running `test '$((10#$(date +%W)%4))' -eq 1` gets me `sh: 1: test: Illegal number: $((10#$(date +%W)%4))`. When you use a single quote, it prevents interpretation and gives you the literal string, which is of course not a number (`-eq` performs a numeric match, `=` is a string match).

Comment: Actually, neither **a** nor **c** will work due to the issue of needing to escape percent signs. See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1006379/209449).

Comment: thanks, i followed the option b and it works. Option c and a , doesnt do it

Comment: @beardblack I have changed description of option `a`. Anyway option `b` is safest IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this would work:

```sh
30 13 * * 6/4 /bin/bash /backup/test.sh
```

I'm not sure if it'll function as desired, but if my understanding of `man 5 crontab` is right, it'll run every fourth Saturday (but possibly not the exact days as your code specifies).

---

Also note that you need to escape percent signs in crontabs and they can't do bashisms like base 10 via `10#` (unless you use `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the top of your crontab or your `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`).

Maybe try this instead:

```sh
30 13 * * 6   test $((1$(date +%%W)%%4)) -eq 1 && /bin/bash /backup/test.sh
```

This takes out the bashism and replaces it with a concatenation that otherwise absorbs the leading zeros (`107%4` == `7%4` == `3` since 100 is divisible by 4). It also escapes the percent signs so crontab doesn't try to interpret them.